# Multi Page PDF merging with data file

Tags: pdf, merge, pdf-generation, multipage

We are trying to add a code to a multipage pdf file.

Let's say there's 1000 pages in the pdf file.
Every six pages corresponds to 1 account.
So those six pages need the same account number.
Then the following six would get a different account number.

ETC.

Has anyone ever run across something that would perform this function?
Can the pdf link to a data file, or would it have to use simple page numbering?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just want to add some text (account number) of particular sets of pages? Which platform you're working with -- .NET or Java or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically add whatever you want to any subset of pages in a PDF using a variety of PDF librarys, commercial or OSS.

Can you be more specific?